# Live example of GWT

Tags: gwt

I am looking for a website created using GWT such that it has the feature of drag and drop of objects in the UI. Please suggest me some websites created in GWT which have very intuitive UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first have a look here: [The GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCheckBox)
or [The Vaadin Showcase](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler)
or [The Smart GWT Showcase](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#main)

After that try [gwt sites](http://www.gwtsite.com/whos-using-gwt/) and [qwt demos](http://www.gwtsite.com/gwt-demos/).

Comment: Thanks Oliholz actually I am looking for some website which implemeted something like this http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#BinExample

Answer (score 0):

Try : [The GWT ArcisWeb](http://code.google.com/p/acris/).
It's also like Content Management Framework